# Infinitesimal rotation around an arbitrary axis S0(3)

Tags: euclidean-geometry, rotations

In my script, I am reading about the case of a small infinitesimal rotation and it's approximation.
If $R$ is the geometrical rotation, and we consider a vector $\vec{OM}$,an infinitesimal angle $d\alpha$, and for simplicity a rotation around the z-axis, then (in the script) we have:

$$R_{\vec u}(d\alpha)\vec{OM}=\vec{OM} + d\alpha \vec u\times \vec{OM}$$

But, as I said $\vec u = \vec e_z$

Then:

$$R_{\vec {e_z}}(d\alpha)\vec{OM}=\vec{OM} + d\alpha \vec {e_z}\times \vec{OM}$$

The formula it seems to me as incorrect. If we consider a counterclockwise (pozitive) rotation around the z-axis, and$\vec{OM}= b\vec e_y$. If we perform the infinitesimal rotation,  $\vec {OM}$ will change into a vector that has a pozitive x-component. But if you would apply the above formula for this case of a rotation, you'd end up having another vector with a negative x-component. So what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you rotate $e_y$ by a right-angle around the $z$-axis according to the right-hand rule, you should get $-e_x$ with a negative sign, no?

Comment: If you are looking the xy-plane from above, and you rotate counterclockwise w.r.t the z-axis, the whole xy-plane moves counterclockwise, the x and y axis are rotating with the same angle and both counterclockwise, therefore you get the new vector in the region with $x \ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$

Comment: If you rotate the positive $y$-axis counterclockwise by $90^\circ$, you get the negative $x$-axis. Should I upload a picture?

Comment: Yes I understand that and you get the x-axis in the y-axis. And for 90 degree angle change, counterclockwise, the $\vec{OM}=b\vec{e_y}$ becomes  $\vec{OM}=b\vec{e_x}$. Because when I perform rotation, I rotate the platform, not the vector which points at some point in space

Comment: But this means that $\vec{OM}$ enters the region in which $x\ge 0$

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/re6rR5v.png) is a picture of how $e_y$ is rotated to $-e_x$ around the $z$-axis by $90^\circ$. I have no idea what you mean by "platform, not the vector," but it sounds irrelevant. Maybe you mean changing the coordinate system itself? If so that's not what's happening here.

Comment: Yes, change of the coordinate system. The vector who can point at a physical object, doesn't change. It's coordinates are result of the reference frame, which we through a rotation change it. Consequently the coordinates must change,no?

Comment: The vector is changed by the rotation. The coordinate system is not. This should be the default assumption given what you've written in the question, no? Is there anything in the context that would give you the impression otherwise? Perhaps it's a good idea to cite your source too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135388/discussion-between-imbaf-and-runway44).